# How to navigate text by skipping entire words using the arrow keys on Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editing

In Mac OS X, Bash, and Emacs, I can navigate quickly in long text areas by pressing `Alt` + `<arrow key direction>`. Is there a Windows equivalent, perhaps a third party hack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. Just <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>.